# How do I upload copied levels in Geometry Dash?

Tags: geometry-dash

So, to clarify, I copied a copy of Stereo Madness, and I can't upload it. I did change it quite a bit, though, so it's not completely the same as Stereo Madness. I can upload any other level, but not that one. I want to know if there is any reason that I can't upload it, like if Geometry Dash doesn't allow people to upload copied levels (though I'm pretty sure that's not the case).

Comment: Did you copy it from the game files? Or a different person?

Comment: @Alex I copied it from somebody that [I assume] copied it from the game files. Don't worry about it. I figured out the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things to check:

1. You need to verify the level first by playing it yourself. I don't think you need to complete it, because I have seen levels that are incomplete (some just drop off and you have about 30 seconds of nothing; and others that are just impossible to finish due to a block being out of place, etc)
2. Try upgrading to the latest version. Some changes in the versions will not allow you to upload a level if you are using an earlier version.
3. Make sure you are connected to the internet (that's an obvious one).
4. Make sure your profile hasn't been banned. There are several reasons why users can be banned, and this will stop you from being able to upload levels.
5. File size may contribute to this issue. If a file is too large, the servers will reject it. Reduce the length of the level, or try trimming some blocks etc. to reduce the file size, and try again.

Comment: thanks for answering! after reading your answer I looked it up and apparently there is a bug where a lot of people can't upload objects with 80+ objects in it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the level you want to upload
2. Beat the level
3. Click on the upload button
4. Request rating, allow or don't allow pass, etc.
5. Click on the upload button
6. Watch your copied level go on the internet!

**NOTE:** There is a bug in GD that will sometimes delete your level from the server, watch out for this.